# Displaying datatable column values in dollars in Shiny r

Tags: r, datatable, datatables, shiny

I have a datatable where one of the columns should be expressed in dollars and some as percentages. I've been looking around and I'm still not sure how to do it - seems like it would be easy?

The trickier part is I have another data table where only certain entries need to be expressed as dollars (i.e. not whole rows or whole columns) - is there a way to handle this?

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your datatable (myData) is 2 columns by 10 rows.

You want the second row to be in dollars:

```
myData[,2]<-sapply(myData[,2],function(x) paste0("$",x))
```

Or, you want rows 6 to 10 in the first column to be percentages:

```
myData[6:10,1]<-sapply(myData[6:10,1],function(x) paste0(x,"%"))
```

Or, you want rows 1 to 5 in the second column to be in dollars, you can do:

```
myData[1:5,2]<-sapply(myData[1:5,2],function(x) paste0("$",x))
```

Comment: Thanks - this approach worked perfectly. Only I used the formatting functions from the scales library with sapply.