# How to always display 3 decimal places in DataTables in R Shiny?

Tags: r, datatables, decimal, shiny

I need to display the data in my table for 3 decimal places but it turns out that it doesn't display 3 decimal places when I run my application. Though when I try to interact with it it displays 3 decimal places.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try `options(digits = 3)` ; I would just use the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033941/displaying-datatable-column-values-in-dollars-in-shiny-r?rq=1   and combine it with a  `format` or `print` statement which can include the number of digits to use

Comment: If you want this post to be useful to others, please modify it by including your code. I down-voted your post but will reverse it if you address this issue.

Answer (score 50):

You can use `DT::formatRound` function. It take list of columns and number of digits to render:

```
library(DT)

set.seed(323)
data.frame(x=runif(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rpois(10, 1)) %>%
    datatable() %>%
    formatRound(columns=c('x', 'y'), digits=3)
```

[image]

Just remember about using `DT::renderDataTable` in the server function and `DT::dataTableOutput` in the UI.

Comment: It would have been better if you would've shown code snippet that could be used in Shiny instead of R Console !